# Create MySQL-Index to prevent doublepost?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `comments` with the (simplified) rows `id`, `article_id`, `user_id` and `text`.

Now I had an idea. Can I somehow create an unique index over `article_id`, `user_id` and `text` to prevent doubleposting directly from the database design?

How would I do that since `text` is from type `TEXT` and refuses to be indexed?

Comment: You could eliminate the auto-increment `id` field (I'm assuming its AI), and make `article_id`, `user_id` and `text` a compound primary key.

Comment: When I try to `ALTER TABLE comments ADD PRIMARY KEY ( article_id , user_id , text )` I get `#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'text' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: If Brian or I answered your question, please mark the question as answered. If not, what are you still having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

you mean to prevent accidental double click on 'save' button? Or prevent posting the same exact text say a week later? If it is the first one, may be just disable your button on first click. If second, you should probably run a hash function on your text field to see if a match already exists for that user on that article. Or add an extra field which is a hash function of your text field and create your unique composite key using that. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698884/mysql-unique-text-field-using-additional-hash-field)

Comment: This is mainly to prevent double posting. Especially when you post something and then use the "BACK" function of your browser, it will send the POST data again. Any idea to prevent this other than by database design?

Comment: Your idea to prevent it through db design is better. Will prevent duplicate posting forever, not just due to 'back'ing.

Answer (score 1):

To create an `INDEX` on a `TEXT` field, you need to specify the index length, like the error is hinting at. This is will only index part of your text field, so you may want to consider using a different field as part of the index, like maybe a `DATE` field - article names are unique by day then, or something like that.

```
INDEX UniqueArticle (article_id, user_id, text(100));
```

**For MyISAM tables**

```
The maximum key length is 1000 bytes. This can also be changed by changing the source and recompiling. For the case of a key longer than 250 bytes, a larger key block size than the default of 1024 bytes is used.
```

**For InnODB tables**

```
Index key prefixes can be up to 767 bytes. See [Section 12.1.8, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”][1].
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Also see: [Problem in using TEXT field in mysql Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374326/problem-in-using-text-field-in-mysql-table)